# sliding effect with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i have seen a nice sliding effect in this site:

http://www.fnxcard.com/

browse to the bottom of page and there are some icons there that have a smooth sliding movement.
i don't think they used jquery but i want to know what the jquery plugin is with this usage.

Comment: i went to look at the source to help you but they use tables thats a pain in the ass to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/download) + [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

The jQuery Easing Plugin will allow you to get that variable speed effect. You might have noticed that their animation changes speed as it animates (slow, faster, slow).

The jQuery Accordion plugin is only for a vertical accordion effect. If you need it to run horizontally just do a google search for "jquery horizontal accordion." I found [this one](http://ajaxian.com/archives/horizontal-accordion-20-for-jquery), and many others.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jqueryui accordion widget. I don't know if it can do horizontal sliding, but it can probably be adapted.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

Try kwicks for jquery

http://www.jeremymartin.name/examples/kwicks.php?example=1

Comment: is it with mootools? i need a jquery one.

Comment: @hd that link **is jquery** kwicks, inspired by mootools kwicks.